# Build ASP.NET Core 1.1 preview4 project in Docker-image microsoft/aspnetcore-build:1.1.0-msbuild

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-1.1

I am currently trying to get an ASP.NET Core 1.1 testproject to build within the microsoft/aspnetcore-build:1.1.0-msbuild docker image.

I am running Docker on Windows 10 Pro 64 and have the newest CLI/SDK (1.0.0-preview4-004233) installed. And I think there lies the problem. The current image uses (1.0.0-preview3-004056) and throws an error "error MSB4057: The target Restore does not exist in the project." when I execute "dotnet restore" within the running container in interactive mode.

My question is:
Is it the version mismatch that creates the error or am I missing something? My guess is that it has to do with some msbuild specific changes between preview3 and preview4.
Can I build my own docker image that uses the right SDK version? Links to good tutorials are very appreciated.

Steps to replicate:

- Install the newest [1.1 SDK](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#windowscmd)
- Open Powershell and navigate in an new and empty project folder
- Validate that you have preview4 "dotnet --info"
- Create new project "dotnet new -t Web"
- Open the *.csproj file change netcoreapp1.0 to netcoreapp1.1 and
  Microsoft.NETCore.App Version to "1.1.0".
- Restore packages "dotnet restore"
- Test with "dotnet run"
- Start docker-container in interactive mode
  docker run -it --rm -v "$pwd:/sln" --workdir /sln microsoft/aspnetcore-build:1.1.0-msbuild
- Within the running container use "dotnet restore" to force the error

Cheers
Martin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tooling is still in preview, and there are huge movements about xproj/csproj project file format. So it's very probable that differences between preview3 and preview4 are critical for your project.

Install appropriate (preview3) CLI to your computer.

There is no user-friendly listing of al versions on MS site, but [in docker image you can see download location](https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker/blob/master/1.1/debian/sdk/msbuild/Dockerfile#L31) like this:

```
https://dotnetcli.blob.core.windows.net/dotnet/Sdk/$DOTNET_SDK_VERSION/dotnet-dev-debian-x64.$DOTNET_SDK_VERSION.tar.gz
```

Replace variables with desired values: `1.0.0-preview3-004056` and `dotnet-dev-win-x64.1.0.0-preview3-004056.exe` (second is guess using up-to-date file names from [download page](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/core)).

Now you need to set you app to use appropriate tooling version (now you have two installed). Create `global.json` file with:

```
{
  "sdk": {
    "version": "1.0.0-preview3-004056"
  }
}
```

To verify: running `dotnet --version` from solution dir (or below) will print `1.0.0-preview3-004056`, while running from any other folder will print `1.0.0-preview4-004233`